# Few commutative algebra questions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

A few commutative algebra questions for which I have no reference

For $P$ = "catenarian", "coherent", " Jacobson":

1- is an arbitrary product of rings satisfying $P$, a ring satisfying $P$?

2- if a ring $A$ satisfies: for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$, the localization $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ satisfies property $P$, is it true that $A$ itself satisfies property $P$?

Comment: @nfdc23: your example for number 1 seems to be zero-dimensional, hence catenary and Jacobson. Or am I missing something? (As I read it, the OP asks separate questions for each of these properties.)

Comment: Yes, the questions are separate.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: Oops, I thought that catenary and Jacobson rings are noetherian by definition. If not then the definition of catenarity only involves localizations of $A$ at primes, so #2 is tautologically true for "catenary" and #2 for Jacobson is true (and uninteresting) for silly reasons: the only local rings that are Jacobson are those with a unique prime, so if every $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is Jacobson then $A$ has no strict containment of primes, so each prime is maximal, so $A$ is trivially Jacobson. For #1 an infinite product of fields fails coherence; I'll mull over the rest of #1.

Comment: #1 fails for $P$ = Jacobson. $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$, the profinite completion of the integers, is reduced, but has nontrivial Jacobson radical $J$. On the other hand, $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}} \simeq \prod_p\mathbf{Z}_p$, where each of the factors is Jacobson. 
To see $J\neq 0$, you may produce lots of nonzero elements in $J$ by defining a "logarithm" $\log : \widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^{\times}\to\mathbf{Z}$ and checking its image is not $(0)\subset\mathbf{Z}$. Say $\log(x) := \lim_{n\to\infty}(x^{n!}-1)/n!$. Its image is in $J$ and $\neq(0)$, hence gives nonzero elements in $J$. In fact, it is $2J$.

Comment: The problem is that arbitrary products of commutative rings may introduce lots of units, building up elements inside the Jacobson radical.

Comment: A nice example.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the second question about coherence, Theorem 3 in M.E.Harris, *Some results on coherent rings II,* Glasgow Math. J. 8 (1967) 123-126 says:

> There exists a non-coherent ring $R$ such that $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is coherent for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$.

Concerning the second question about catenarity, the answer is obviously yes.